# Can't run Apache Maven via command line on El Capitan

Tags: command-line

I have installed [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/index.html) 3.3.9 and tried to run it with command line using `mvn`. 
For this purpose, I added the following symlink but it doesn't work :

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/share/java/maven3/bin/mvn /usr/local/bin
```

I tried first :

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/share/java/maven3 /usr/local/bin
```

But `Man mvn` and `mvn -v` don't return anything except errors.
Any idea what I should do ? 
I'm using last version of El Capitan. 
Thanks.

EDIT :

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/mvn returns lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  35  2 aoû 21:34 /usr/local/bin/mvn -> opt/local/share/java/maven3/bin/mvn
```

My PATH contains a bunch of stuff:

```
/Users/sbdy/anaconda3/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/java:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/X11/bin: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try adding a / to the front of opt. More importantly what errors?

Comment: Thanks. But mvn -v still returns "-bash: mvn: command not found" and man mvn "No manual entry for mvn".

Comment: What does ls -l /usr/local/bin/mvn show and what is your path

Comment: Mark, I've edited my question

Comment: You are still missing the / as the first character in front of opt/local/...

Comment: I've corrected it but this is not the problem it seems...

Comment: You need to use the absolute path beginning with /

Comment: Where exactly? @Mark

Comment: In the ln command you edited here but from the result of ls you have not actually done it

Comment: @Mark, exactly...so I corrected it and it yields what is expected. Now, I get the error "JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly. We cannot execute /usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java". I've done what suggest klanomath but stille the same story. I've made some improvement though lol

Comment: Oh, mvn -h work but still no output for "man mvn"

Answer (score 1):

I assume your JAVA_HOME is not configured properly. This will result in an info and error output entering `mvn -h` or `mvn -v`.

To install Java 8 and Maven properly do the following:

- Download and install the latest [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
- Open Terminal and enter `/usr/libexec/java_home`. The result should be (as of August 2016):

  ```
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home
  ```
- Download and unzip [Maven](http://apache.openmirror.de/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.zip). Move the resulting folder to an appropriate folder (e.g. /opt/)
- In Terminal enter `nano .bash_profile`. Add the lines

  ```
  export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
  export PATH=/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:/...other_paths_already_in_your_profile..:$PATH
  ```

  save the file to disk and quit nano with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>
- Source your modified profile with `source .bash_profile` or better restart Terminal.

If you have installed *maven* and/or *java* with *[MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/)* or *[homebrew](http://brew.sh/)*, the approach is similar the paths to *Java/Maven* may differ though.

Comment: Hi, I followed what you said... Maven is installed under /opt/local/share/java/maven3. /usr/libexec/java_home returns /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home even if it's updated to 8.0_101.jdk version, so it might be the problem

Comment: @loukios You may simply remove the folder /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk if you don't need anymore (and the folder /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk is present).

Comment: Thanks, i've just done it, but still does not work...I really don't get it!

Comment: @loukios Please add to your question how you installed Maven (e.g. homebrew/macports/directly) and which mods you made to your ENV variables – that means e.g. posting the content of your .bash_profile (please redact it if it contains passwords or similar stuff)